# how to get out of inner loop without breaking

Tags: python

so I am working on this program and I am trying to remove duplicates from an array and I wanna leave the inner loop and go back to the outer loop after every iteration but I don't want the inner loop to start over because now everytime I break out of the inner loop the next iteration the inner loop starts all over again so num is always 1

```
 def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        curr = nums[i+1]
        for num in nums:
            if num == curr:
                print('removed ' , num)
            break
```

Comment: Don't use an inner loop. Just use `if curr in nums:`

Comment: The inner loop is always going to find a match, since it's just checking whether an element of the list is in the same list. It's not checking for duplicates, because it doesn't skip its own index.

Comment: @Barmar but that would remove every number

Comment: So does your code.

Comment: @Barmar current is the next number after num so its skipping and looking at the one after it

Comment: @rawanarafat is it mandatory that you print every removed element ? Or do you only have to remove the duplicates, and printing was just there for debug ?

Comment: @vultkayn no I am just doing it to make sure I am removing the right elements

Comment: @rawanarafat But the inner loop doesn't skip it, it loops over the entire list, including `i+1`, which is `current`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a set then

```py
nums = list(set(nums))
```

Comment: Any time the answer is this simple, it's a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: Noted for next time